# Trying to identify duplicate key in a Json structure using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have 2 arrays of the same length and when comparing them keys of a JSON structure. if they have the same name and are case sensitive, then do nothing but if they have the same name and case insensitive then throw an error.

```
array1 = {"firstName": "Rahul", "lastName":"Peru"},
array2 = {"FirstName": "Sam", "lastName": "Curran"}
```

When comparing the keys of both arrays. Not converting them into lower case, Will "firstName" === "FirstName" ?
and

```
if("firstName" === "FirstName"){
// then throw duplication error beacuse it will create one more row in the database as
   they have same name but case insensitive
}
if ("lastName" === "lastName"){
//do nothing
}
```

I am looking for some logic.
Please someone help me.

Comment: they are not arrays, just json objects

Comment: I already told you that they are JSON structure. I just named them array1 and array2.

Answer (score 0):

=== converts values to the same-type before comparison. In this case,

```
console.log("Hello" == "hello");
console.log("Hello" === "hello");
```

Will both return false, characters are obviously different. You could if matching regardless of case apply

```
stringvariable.toUpperCase();
or
stringvariable.toLowerCase();
```